# How do I set up a .pem login for my servers?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I have a couple of ubuntu droplets on digital ocean

I have set up a username password based login. But I am not comfortable with the idea.

What i would ideally like is a amazon like login where I have a `identity.pem` sort of file. I will share this file with the people in the team. They login by saying `ssh webuser@website_ip` after doing an `ssh-add`

How do I set up a login like this?

I do not want to add ssh-keygen on each developers machine and then add the contents of the public key to `.ssh/authorised_keys`. For one thing, this seems like too much work for each developer.

Let me know if it is possible. Thanks

Comment: Giving people a shared login really is a bad idea. You really should just get them all to generate ssh keys it takes a couple of minutes.

Comment: Sometimes, it is not viable to have the SSH keys for each specific user. I work for a law firm, and we use shared PEM keys all the time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a straightforward enough process, though as has already been commented, a shared login is an extremely bad idea. In this situation, all users have equal access and you won't be able to track what work is carried out as which user. With that in mind however, the following process will give you what you want. On the machine in question, while logged in as the shared user:

Lets keep everything in one place:

> cd .ssh/

Generate the file id_dsa from which we will create the PEM file:

> ssh-keygen -t dsa -b 2048

Generate the private key PEM file:

> openssl dsa -in id_dsa -outform pem > pk_dsa.pem

Generate the public key PEM file for distribution to the users:

> openssl dsa -in pk_dsa.pem -pubout -out pub_dsa.pem

The final pub_dsa.pem is the file you're looking for.

Comment: Hello! My server tells me that DSA has to be 1024 bytes. The final pem file that I have distrivuted asks me for a passphrase. Trying to remove passphrase by `openssl rsa -in <file.pem> -out <file.nocrypt.pem>` tells me unable to load Private key. `openssl rsa -in <file.pem> -check` tells `139688383772488:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:703:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY`

Comment: This is not working for me, Still asking for password as well passphrase.
I am using ubuntu 14.04